# Why are certain terms sometimes written in hiragana and sometimes in katakana?

Tags: katakana, orthography, hiragana

I was typing something up and when I went to type apple in Japanese, the Microsoft IME on the computer I was using defaulted to リンゴ in katakana. But from what I remember seeing online and out in the real world from time to time, りんご is usually written in hiragana as such. What was weirder to me was that when I typed orange in Japanese, it defaults to みかん in hiragana.

I have come across [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44612/why-is-%e3%82%8a%e3%82%93%e3%81%94-written-in-hiragana) and [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1930/why-are-katakana-preferred-over-hiragana-or-kanji-sometimes), as well as [this question](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-katakana-widely-used-to-express-animals-and-plants-in-Japanese) over on Quora trying to find an answer.

The gist of what those three links explain, if I understand them all correctly, is that writing a word in hiragana is usually because its kanji form contains non-standard kanji and is thus for ease of reading, and katakana is used either for emphasis/ease of reading or in academic contexts.

What I was wondering was, unless you are discussing something in an academic context, are words that contain non-joyo kanji almost always written in hiragana?